# Azure Pipelines connecting to Azure SQL Database AAD - Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I am attempting to connect to a Azure SQL DB with an AAD account as part of my Azure pipeline. Roughly I have the following:

An Azure pipeline with an associated service connection.
An Azure SQL DB with the AAD admin set to the service principal (of the connection).
An Azure CLI task which gets the bearer token of the service principal.

I then have a Azure Powershell script that uses the bearer token to connect to the DB:

```
$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$($sqlServer),1433;Initial Catalog=$($sqlDB);Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
$conn.AccessToken = $env:ACCESSTOKEN
$conn.Open()
```

This results in the following error:

```
Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>
```

The Agent running the pipeline is allowed through the SQL Server firewall.

In the DB logs the error code is 18456 and the state is 132 (AAD failure).

I have tested this manually using Azure CLI logging in using the service connections service principal, requesting the bearer token and then connecting to the db (using the code above) and this works.

If I compare the bearer token of the Pipeline test and the Azure CLi manual test, they are identical (apart from exp, uti and aio)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide the cli script to get access token?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work? I'm facing the same issue and can't seem to get a token that works in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-token):

> This authentication method allows middle-tier services to obtain JSON Web Tokens (JWT)

You need to use the [id_token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-token)s for Azure AD authentication. From your script, it seems that you are using the pipeline environment access token.

On the other hand, you could navigate to **Azure Portal -> Azure Sql -> Query Editor** page.
Then you could select the `Active Directory authentication` and check if you could log into the database successfully.

[image: Azure Sql]

If you have the issue `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>` in this page,
you could try to add the target account as `Active Directory admin` on SQL Server or  [create contained users mapped to Azure AD identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities).

[image: AAD admin]

In addition, you can also log in Azure SQL with Azure AD account and password.

Script:

```
$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$($sqlServer),1433;Initial Catalog=$($sqlDB);Persist Security Info=False;User ID:User account;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Password;" 
$conn.Open()
```

**Updates:**

For access token:

You could try to run the Azure CLI command in Azure Clould shell:

```
az login

az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net
```

Then you could get the Access Token.

[image: Access token]

Based on my test, if you use this Access token to connect Azure Sql , it could work as expected.

**Updates2:**

Get it . If you set the Service Principal  as the AD Admin. The **manual Service Principal type service connection** could work.

[image: Manual]

For example:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: manual service connection name
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     
     az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net
  enabled: false
```

The Access token could be used to connect Azure Sql.

Comment: Yes - Im getting the service principals access token  (this principal is also the AAD Admin of the Azure SQL DB

This is the approach:

 az account get-access-token --resource=https://database.windows.net --query accessToken

Then Im passing it to the connection:

$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$($sqlServer),1433;Initial Catalog=$($sqlDB);Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
$conn.AccessToken = $env:ACCESSTOKEN
$conn.Open()

I wouldnt expect to pass the id token?

Comment: @iasksillyquestions. Please check my update. You could run the  `az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net` command to get the Access Token.

Comment: This is what Im doing already (in an Azure CLI task). See my comment above (and my question). I expected this to work also. Its not a SQL DB firewall issue or a CAP issue either. Stumped.

Comment: You need to run  `az login` command before the get access token command. I suggest that you could run these command with the **cloud shell** in Azure Portal. Then you will get the valid access token.

Comment: The pipeline is already authenticated with a service principal. I wouldnt have thought az login was appropriate? Wont it try to pop a dialog (which you wouldnt want as part of a pipeline)?

Comment: Please check if  the service principal type is automatic in service connection. I could get the error when it is automatic . You could try to create a manual service principal type service connection. In addition，the `az login` is used in cloud shell. If possible, please try to get the access token from cloud shell (this is not a part of the pipeline), then you could check if it could work.

Comment: Are you suggesting getting the access token from cloud shell and then hard coding that into the pipeline as a test?

Our service connection is automatic. I'll also try creating a manual one - although Im unsure as to why this would matter

Comment: Im also assuming that youre suggesting logging in as the service principal in cloud shell? Hard coding an access token into the pipeline seems like a bad idea though (I'd have to request a long lived access token) - happy to use it to see if I get 2 different access tokens in these 2 scenarios.

Comment: Hi friend. I have updated the answer again.  This is a workaround and some explainations for this question.

Comment: I had set the Service Principal as the AAD Admin of the SQL server. This is why I expected this to work?

Comment: Get it. I use the manual Service Principal to get the Access token.  And it could work as expected.

Comment: So I created a Manual Service Connection. I recieve an access token but I get the same error message Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>

Comment: And finally  - if  manually run az login and then get a bearer token  manually for the service prinicipal associated the service connection - I can open a connection. Via the pipeline which is using the same princaple it doesnt open The bearer tokens in both cases are basically identical.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion solution @KevinLu-MSFT and I am too receiving this error posted by the OP. 'Login Failed for user <token-identified-principal>. No idea how to resolve this.

Comment: I have resolved this by adding permissions for Service Principal on a database level using SQL Server Management Studio:

    CREATE USER [ServicePrincipalName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
    ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [ServicePrincipalName];
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER ServicePrincipalName];
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [ServicePrincipalName];

Comment: @botja thats what I did as well, but it works on one db and doesnt on another db in the same server

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Connection String to;

```
"Data Source=<SQLServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;"
```

The Access Token you're using should be correct as you're generating it from "https://database.windows.net/".

Comment: This results in exactly the same error message

"Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>"

Answer (score 0):

`az account get-access-token` did **NOT** work for me. then I completely **changed code to this and it worked**.. .here is a sample (also logout any previous logins as sometimes $authResult was in faulted state and did not have the access token within). You can tweak this to your needs.

```
$tenant = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
$applicationId = $(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "MyServicePrincipal").ApplicationId
$clientSecret = "yyyy-yyyyy-yyyy" 
$subscriptionId = "xyxy-xyxy-xyxy-xyxy"

$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$clientSecret.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $applicationId, $secstr

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenant -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred


$resourceAppIdURI = 'https://database.windows.net/'

$authority = ('https://login.windows.net/{0}' -f $tenant)
$ClientCred = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($applicationId, $clientSecret)
$authContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($authority)
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdURI, $ClientCred)
$Token = $authResult.Result.AccessToken

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$SQLServerName = "sql-myApplicationDbServer-dev.database.windows.net"
$DatabaseName = 'sqldb-myApplicationDb-dev'

$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=$DatabaseName;Connect Timeout=30"
$conn.AccessToken = $($Token)
conn.Open() -- works for me
```

i'd also suggest to set the Sql server AAD admin to an AAD group, and make the servcie principal as a member of that group. Its easier to manage that way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a slightly old question, but I had this exact same problem and in my case it was due to trying to run both the token request and the SQL command within the same Azure CLI task in our Azure DevOps pipeline.

When I switched out the SQL command to a standard PowerShell task and passed in the token as a parameter, this resolved the login issue against the database for some reason. I kept the token request in the existing Azure CLI task but set an output variable with the contents of the token.

I can't really work out why this is... I know you've indicated your token request and SQL calls were in separate scripts already, but I wonder if potentially the issue was that the SQL call was in an Azure PowerShell task as opposed to just a vanilla PowerShell one? Maybe there's some odd interaction between the authenticated service connection the Azure PowerShell task is using and the call to open the DB connection or something.

Hopefully this helps someone anyway - felt compelled to post as this was the one SO question that let me know I wasn't alone

--- **EDIT** ---

I've switched to running a single script as an Azure PowerShell task that gets the token using:

`(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token`

instead of the Azure CLI command `az account get-access-token`.

This can then open the SQL connection in the same script without issue.

Comment: Have since confirmed that an Azure PowerShell task works just as well as a vanilla one. So must have been something about trying to open the SQL connection within the same Azure CLI task that caused the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Azure PowerShell

$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token

Azure CLI

$token = az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net/ --query "accessToken" --output tsv

As you can see there is a tiny difference in the URI (that makes all the difference).